# Why doesn't a properies code block get hit when stepping though C# code?

Tags: c#, class, properties

I'm trying to understand how Properties work. I've found that stepping though sample code can be very helpful. But When I step through a small program with a simple class and Property, the Property never gets hit. Which makes me wonder if its even being used. With the code below I can see that the private variables of the class are touched but nothing else. I'm confused. Plus if anyone has found a site or video that was their "ah hah" moment for understanding class properties I'd love to see it.

```
using System;

public class Customer
{
    private int m_id = -1;

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return m_id;
        }
        set
        {
            m_id = value;
        }
    }

    private string m_name = string.Empty;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return m_name;
        }
        set
        {
            m_name = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomerManagerWithProperties
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Customer cust = new Customer();

        cust.ID = 1;
        cust.Name = "Amelio Rosales";

        Console.WriteLine(
                "ID: {0}, Name: {1}",
                cust.ID,
                cust.Name);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Visula Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: **Plus if anyone has found a site or video that was their "ah hah" moment for understanding class properties I'd love to see it.**  Class properties are public variables.  What is your exact question about class properties?

Comment: properties are equivalent to "getters" and "setters" in Java and other languages. Just that they're a little more formal. It's like exposing a field except that they can be calculated or just have a get or just a set. It's a way to expose values without violating the principals of encapsulation purported by object oriented design.

Comment: And the reason why they're stepped over by default in C# is just because they're usually just getting a field and therefore not very interesting. In addition to just turning off this feature you can also right click on a given line of code during debugging and select "Step Into..." and you can explicitly step into a part of an expression in that line, including properties.

Comment: @Ramhound, class properties are in NO WAY public variables. They are getter and setter methods with syntactical sugar and a peice of metadata specifying that they combine to form a property. Instance variables do not have the ability to modify state, or change every time you get or set them. Properties do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to modify the default debugger settings to step into properties (`Tools|Options ->Debugging->General`):

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it, with a screenshot none-the-less!

Answer (score 1):

You should check your settings in Visual Studio, in: Tools -> Options -> Debugging, there is the option:

```
Step over properties and operators (Managed only)
```

Make sure this is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010, the default is to step over properties. You can change this behavior in the Tools -> Options -> General -> Step over properties and operators (Managed only).